Gradle Download Timeout
I downloaded Studio 3.6 because the Jellyfish version couldn't download a gradle  resource back then. Now, i'm back on Feb 2020 version 3.6 and i'm still getting the same issue; the IDE refuses to download gradle 5.6.4-all.zip and it is really frustrating. Can someone, please, guide me in normal terms on how to resolve this issue please. Have spent about 2 weeks on this issue please.
Thought it was network related as the error showed download timed out. Have tried with my phone's hotspot without success as well.
Many thanks in advance.
Coker
